# Using regex to get the required text

Tags: regex, perl

I have tezt like this
`[SAME][DIFFERING_VALUES] Name= Ram Mark= 12`

I need to get the value `DIFFERING_VALUES` using regex.

I tried `^\[[A-Z]*` but is picking only SAME. How to get DIFFERING_VALUES ?

Comment: Your `^` ist the beginning of the string. You don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`/g` in list context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) to extract as many matches as possible:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper("[SAME][DIFFERING_VALUES] Name= Ram Mark= 12" =~ /\[([^]]+)\]/g)'
$VAR1 = 'SAME';
$VAR2 = 'DIFFERING_VALUES';
```